# "Android fragment dialog" на основе "layout" файла не отображается заголовок

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, dialogfragment

Как сделать так, чтобы при создании диалога, на основе `layout` файла отображался заголовок диалога?

Код класса моего диалога:

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.EditText;
import net.squirrel.postar.client.R;

public class DialogSaveTrack extends android.app.DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {
private DialogueResultListener listener;
private EditText eDescription;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    listener = (DialogueResultListener) getActivity();

    Dialog dialog = getDialog();
    dialog.setTitle(getText(R.string.dialog_add_description));
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL , 0);

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_description, null);
    eDescription = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.eDescription);
    v.findViewById(R.id.bContinue).setOnClickListener(this);
    v.findViewById(R.id.bCancel).setOnClickListener(this);

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bCancel:
            dismiss();
            break;
        case R.id.bContinue:
            listener.onDialogResult(eDescription.getText().toString());
            dismiss();
            break;
    }
}
```

}

XML layout-файл :

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/eDescription"/>

<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Continue"
            android:id="@+id/bContinue"/>

    <Button
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:id="@+id/bCancel"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Результат:

[image: Диалог с использованием layout-файла]
  При создании диалога, с помощью "билдера" диалог создается нормально - с заголовком.

Также пробовал:

```
  setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL , 0);
```

Перебирал различные варианты задания `setTitle` в различных функциях обработчиков диалогов, искал в интернете, смотрел примеры кода, но ответа не нашел. И вроде по умолчанию заголовки есть...
  Пожалуйста кто знает или у кого есть предположения подскажите.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте стиль

```
<style name="CustomDialog" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
</style>
```

И используйте в диалоге его:

```
setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.CustomDialog);
```

Comment: Добавил setStyle в onCreate и соответствующую тему, помогло спасибо.